How can I stop Xcode Preview Canvas showing "AutoFill" popup on TextFields
"Sometimes" Xcode Preview Canvas shows a "AutoFill" popup on TextFields.

I'm not sure what I pressed to cause this to happen. How can i make it go away without restarting Xcode?

It appears that you were mistakenly holding control while pressing on the text field.

You can get rid of it by clicking out side the text field or pressing command + optional + enter twice to turn off the preview and then back on.
